# Breadth first search code in C, possible stack overflow

Tags: c, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I wrote a code for breadth first search in C using a compressed sparse row data structure. The code seems to work well for one graph but returns an error for another graph file. It works well for [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmmbtov7dzjmzw9/rmat-100-2000.graph?dl=0) but throws an error for [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sap7w58q2cv94th/large.graph?dl=0) Being new to C programming, I can't find the cause of the problem and will appreciate any help

I tried checking the condition for the while loop. The condition for the loop is true when the code hangs up and returns an error. I am running this code on CodeBlocks 16.01 with the mingw compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Declaring a struct type to hold

int main(){
int n, m, counter, current, x, src, dst;
n=0, m=0, counter = 0, current =0, src = 0, dst = 0;

FILE *fp; //create a pointer to the file directory
fp = fopen("filename.graph","r"); //set the directory pointer to the path of the text file containing graph data
if ((fp == NULL)){ perror("Error, no such file exists \n");  exit(1);} 
//If file not found, print error message and exit the program
else
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%d %d", &n,&m); //read first line of text file to get number of vertices and edges in graph

        struct CSRgraph //Create CSR data structure
            {
                int heads[m];    //Stores heads of edges
                int offsets[n+1]; //Stores information on the number of edges leaving each node
            };
        struct CSRgraph g;  //Create an instance of the CSR graph data structure
        g.offsets[0] = 0; //Set the initial offset value to 0
        g.offsets[n] = m; //Set the offset value of 'phantom' node to the number of edges in graph

        for(x=0;x<m;x++) //iterate over all lines containing edge information in text file
            //Read file and create CSR data structure from information in text file
            {
                fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&src,&dst); //read source and head information from file
                g.heads[x] = dst; //assign head information to the next available slot in data structure
                if (src < n+1) //Check that node is valid
                    {
                        if (src == current) //check that current edge originates from same source as previous edge
                            {
                                counter++; //increment counter for the number of edges that originate from current source
                            }
                        else //Current edge does not originate from previous source. New source node encountered
                            {
                                g.offsets[src] = counter + g.offsets[src -1]; //Update offset value for previous source
                                counter = 1; //restart edge origin counter
                                current = src ; //set current to current source
                            }
                    }

            }

fclose(fp); //Close file after use

int Discovered[n],Queue[n+1],Explored[n], *front_ptr,*end_ptr,*exp_ptr;
front_ptr = Queue;  //Initialize the front pointer to the Queue array
end_ptr = Queue;    //Initialize the end pointer to the Queue array
exp_ptr = Explored; //Initialize the explored pointer to the Explored array

for (x=0;x<n;x++)
{
    Discovered[x] = 0; //An array to track discovered nodes. Not necessarily explored, but nodes that have showed up previously
}
// Advance the pointers in the direction you want
*end_ptr = 0; //setting the first element in the queue as the node 0
end_ptr++; //advancing the end pointer to the next available array spot
Discovered[0] = 1;

while (front_ptr != end_ptr)
    { //Queue is empty if front pointer is the same as end pointer
        int p,curr;
        curr = *front_ptr; //grab the front of the queue and set it as current node
        front_ptr++; //equivalent to removing from element and pushing the next node in line to the front
        *exp_ptr = curr; //set current node to explored
        exp_ptr++; //advance the explored pointer one step

    for (p = g.offsets[curr]; p < g.offsets[curr+1]; p++)
        //iterate over all neighbors of current node
        {
        if (Discovered[g.heads[p]] == 0)
        //if node is not already discovered, set it to discovered, add it to queue and advanced the end pointer of queue one step
            {
                Discovered[g.heads[p]] = 1;
                *end_ptr = g.heads[p];
                end_ptr++;
            }
        }
    }

}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what "inexplicable" error did you receive?

Comment: The program just exits in one case while it completes running in the other case. I should say "inexplicable" is only from my point of reference.

Comment: What is the point of `struct CSRgraph`?  You declare exactly one instance, and then just use it for its members.  This would be merely odd, if not for the fact that struct members are not permitted to have variably-modified type.

Comment: How can you tell that the program "just exits" in the purported error case?  I don't see any place where it emits any output if it successfully opens the target file.  Can you be sure that it did not complete its computation?

Comment: `int heads[m];` as a VLA of `int` with a `m = 108744` is likely causing a StackOverflow... (this will be compiler, OS and memory-model dependent)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: @Ozymandais - I posted an answer changing the VLA members of `CSRgraph` to pointers and allocating storage with `malloc/calloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `int heads[m];` as a VLA of int with `m = 108744` (along with the other 4 VLAs you allocate of `2950` integers) is likely causing a StackOverflow... (this will be compiler, OS and memory-model dependent). To fix the problem, change `CSRgraph` so that members `heads` and `offsets` are pointers and then dynamically allocate storage based on the numbers read from the first line of the file, e.g.

```
typedef struct {    /* typdef for convenience */
    int *heads,
        *offsets;
} CSRgraph_t;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    CSRgraph_t g;                   /* declare instance of struct */
    ...
    /* allocate/validate g.heads & g.offsets */
    if (!(g.heads = malloc (m * sizeof *g.heads))) {
        perror ("malloc-g.heads");
        return 1;
    }
    /* calloc used to zero g.offsets */
    if (!(g.offsets = calloc ((n + 1), sizeof *g.offsets))) {
        perror ("malloc-g.offsets");
        return 1;
    }
    g.offsets[0] = 0;
    g.offsets[n] = m;
    ...
```

(**note:** `calloc` is used on `offsets` to initialize it to all zero as you later compare `p < g.offsets[curr+1]`)

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {    /* typdef for convenience */
    int *heads,
        *offsets;
} CSRgraph_t;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    CSRgraph_t g;                   /* declare instance of struct */
    int n, m, counter, current;
    n = m = counter = current = 0;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    if (fscanf (fp, "%d %d", &n, &m) != 2) {    /* validate EVERY read */
        fputs ("error: invalid format n, m.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate/validate g.heads & g.offsets */
    if (!(g.heads = malloc (m * sizeof *g.heads))) {
        perror ("malloc-g.heads");
        return 1;
    }
    /* calloc used to zero g.offsets */
    if (!(g.offsets = calloc ((n + 1), sizeof *g.offsets))) {
        perror ("malloc-g.offsets");
        return 1;
    }
    g.offsets[0] = 0;
    g.offsets[n] = m;

    for (int x = 0; x < m; x++) {
        int src;    /* src is only needed within scope of loop */
        if (fscanf (fp, "%d %d", &src, &g.heads[x]) != 2) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid format - line %d.\n", x);
        }
        if (src < n+1) {
            if (src == current)
                counter++;
        }
        else {
            g.offsets[src] = counter + g.offsets[src -1];
            counter = 1;    /* restart edge origin counter */
            current = src;  /* set current to current source */
        }
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    int Discovered[n], Queue[n+1], Explored[n], 
        *front_ptr, *end_ptr, *exp_ptr;

    front_ptr = Queue;  /* front pointer to the Queue array */
    end_ptr = Queue;    /* end pointer to the Queue array */
    exp_ptr = Explored; /* explored pointer to the Explored array */

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
        Discovered[x] = 0;

    /* Advance the pointers in the direction you want */
    *end_ptr = 0;
    end_ptr++;
    Discovered[0] = 1;

    while (front_ptr != end_ptr) {
        int curr = *front_ptr;
        front_ptr++;
        *exp_ptr = curr;
        exp_ptr++;

        for (int p = g.offsets[curr]; p < g.offsets[curr+1]; p++) {
            if (Discovered[g.heads[p]] == 0) {
                Discovered[g.heads[p]] = 1;
                *end_ptr = g.heads[p];
                end_ptr++;
            }
        }
    }

    free (g.heads);
    free (g.offsets);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** avoid hardcoding filenames, e.g. `fopen("filename.graph","r")`, `main()` takes arguments, use them to pass the filename as the first argument to your program [and you can read from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided])

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/readgraphsfile ~/tmp/graphfile/large.graph
==17345== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17345== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17345== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17345== Command: ./bin/readgraphsfile ~/tmp/graphfile/large.graph
==17345==
==17345==
==17345== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17345==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17345==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 447,332 bytes allocated
==17345==
==17345== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17345==
==17345== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17345== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It works fine with your `large.graph` file.

Comment: This code works fine. However, I have a follow up question, I guess I only have this question because I'm not so familiar with pointers yet. Suppose I want to recover the elements that are added to the Explored array, how will I do that. I tried looping over all the array positions but got some unexpected results.

Comment: I found the bug. There is either a missing curly bracket right after (src == current), or an extra curly bracket after counter++

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. The other thing I noticed in your code, while comments are very good, if they sprawl across the page and obscure, or make the code more difficult to read, they are working against you in that regard. Short, concise and informative comments are often better than entire sentences. Also, pay attention to the scope required for your variables. If you notice I moved a number of you variables into narrow scope and did away with some altogether (no need for `dst` as it is just assigned to `g.heads[x]`, and no need for `x` accept declared as a loop variable). Good luck.